# get tinyEditor value in javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor

i am using tinyEditor as my text editor, but i donno how to get a tinyEditor textarea's value in javascript.
when i user document.getElementById('texteditor').value; it gives me null. nothing.
anyone know how to fix this problem?

**[this is the site for tinyEditor](http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the standard way is:

```
tinyMCE.get('element-ID').getContent();
```

which element-ID is the id of the textarea used for tinyMCE.

Comment: This seems to be new with their current API. Good find!

Comment: actually, I found it that two years ago but i didn't mention here. sorry for delay !!

Comment: Better late than never! +1

Answer (score 5):

Try this (`editor` is the instance):

```
editor.post();
var textAreaHtml = editor.t.value;
```

Comment: may be you can help me, which editor is better and so lightweight

Comment: It worked for me with this declaration: `new TINY.editor.edit('editor',{ ... }`

Comment: @Mrchief sir this works like charm for me.. thank you very much sir..you save me lots of time....thank you very much sir..

Answer (score 1):

```
editor.i.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

this will return value of editor, but this is hack, this is not valid access, as I can see method for getting content doesn't exists.

so "editor" is name of your editor.